# 'exec' command blocks the running of php script when execute SchTasks

Tags: php, windows-task-scheduler

I use the following script php to schedule task of archive :

```
$archive_command = 'SchTasks /Create /SC monthly /MO lastday /TN archive'.date('Y_m').' /TR PHP_BINARY." ".$SCRIPT_DIR.archive.php /M * /ST 23:30';
exec("$archive_command 2>&1");
```

but when execute `SchTasks` to recreate the same task it blocks the execution of the php script.
How to avoid this blocking  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
pclose(popen("$archive_command 2>&1 &", "r"));
```

**UPDATE:**
I have picked this function from another site :

```
function bgExec($cmd) {
    if(substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r")); 
    } else {
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &"); 
 }
}
```

Comment: yes it works but the following wanning are displayed : (+)Warning: popen() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in .... line                                                                                      (+)Warning: pclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to force shell to return immediately by appending ampersand to the command line with [`popen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php):

```
#                            ⇓
popen("$archive_command 2>&1 &", "r");
```

If this is OK with you, fine. If not, let me know. There is another more complicated way to resolve an issue with starting shell in another thread.

Comment: Are you sure you have tried with `popen` not with `exec`?